Почему не могу открыть соединение с MSSQL в Андроиде
Мне надо соединиться с базой данных, но ошибка вылетает сразу при попытке установить соединение. В коде нет ничего, кроме установки соединения. Пробовал разные версии библиотеки mssql-jdbc. Ничего не помогает.
Ошибка:

java.lang.AssertionError: numMsgsRcvd:1 should be less than numMsgsSent:1

Код:
fun insertDataMainThread(name: String) {
    var connection: Connection? = null
    var preparedStatement: PreparedStatement? = null
    val url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\SQLGA:1433;databaseName=test;encrypt=false;integratedSecurity=false"
    val username = "test"
    val password = "test"

    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password)

    }  catch (e: SQLException) {
        Log.e("DatabaseHelper", "SQLException: ${e.message}", e)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e("DatabaseHelper", "Exception: ${e.message}", e)
    } catch (e: RuntimeException) {
        Log.e("DatabaseHelper", "RuntimeException: ${e.message}", e)
    }catch (e: Throwable) {
        Log.e("DatabaseHelper", "Неизвестная ошибка: ${e.message}", e)
    }finally {
        try {
            preparedStatement?.close()
            connection?.close()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}

Как избавиться от этой ошибки?

как задать хороший вопрос

А где вы тут увидели что это вообще работает на Андроид? https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc

Не думал, что не поддерживается. А что тогда можно использовать?

Ну раз уж база локальная, почему не SQLite, которую андроид поддерживает "из коробки"?

База не локальная, это я для примера написал.

Напрямую надо коннектиться только локальной БД. К удаленной -- через REST или другое API. Вот тут о том же: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79026907/kotlin-java-lang-assertionerror-nummsgsrcvd1-should-be-less-than-nummsgssent1
